# How to take sha-1, sha-256 or MD5 of CDs / DVDs?

Tags: linux, devices, dd, checksum

I just tried burning both a Debian CD *and* a Debian DVD from their *.iso* files and I've got a weird behavior: the checksum of the CD is correct but the one of the DVD ain't.

Here's what working:

- downloaded the two *.iso* files
- verified the checksum of the two *.iso* files
- burn the CD *debian-7.1.0-amd64-CD-1.iso* to a CD
- verify that the CD is correct by issuing:

  dd if=/dev/sr0 | md5sum   (or sha-1 or sha-256)

And this works fine: the checksum(s) I get from the CD by using *dd* and piping into md5, sha-1 or sha-256 do match the official checksums.

Now what I don't get is that I did burn a DVD from the DVD *.iso* --and I know that the file has been correctly downloaded seen that the *.iso* **file** checksum is correct.

However if I put the DVD in the drive and issue the same:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 | md5sum   (or sha-1 or sha-256)
```

then I get a bogus checksum.

The DVD still *looks* correct in that the files all seem to be there.

So here's my question: can I verify that a DVD has been correctly burned by using *dd* and piping its output into md5sum (or sha-1 or sha-256) or is there something "special" that would make *dd* work for verifying burned CDs but not burned DVDs?

*(note that I used *Disk Utility* on OS X to burn both the CD and the DVD)*

Comment: `dd` probably has nothing to do with the problem. It's not doing anything that `cat /dev/sr0 | md5sum` or `md5sum /dev/sr0` wouldn't do, except maybe use a different buffer size, and that won't change the hash. As long as you still have the image file around, you can also run `cmp /dev/sr0 foo.iso` to get some more information on whether they are really different. If it reports EOF on the image file, then the burned disc just has some padding on the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to Gilles answer,

If you still have the ISO image, you could use `cmp` instead of checksums. It would tell you at which byte the difference happens. It would also make the check faster as if there is an error early on, it would tell you right away, whereas the checksum always has to read the entire media.

```
$ cmp /dev/cdrom /path/to/cdrom.iso
```

In case of error it should print something like this

```
/dev/cdrom /path/to/cdrom.iso differ, byte 123456789, line 42
```

In case it's correct it should print *nothing*, or this:

```
cmp: EOF on /path/to/cdrom.iso
```

Which means there is more data on `/dev/cdrom` than in the ISO, most likely zero-padding.

Even before starting any comparisons, you could check the size.

```
$ blockdev --getsize64 /dev/cdrom
123456999
$ stat -c %s /path/to/cdrom.iso
123456789
```

If it's identical, the checksum should match also. If `/dev/cdrom` is larger, it should be zero padded at the end. You could check that with `hexdump`. Use the ISO size for the `-s` parameter.

```
$ hexdump -s 15931539256 -C /dev/cdrom
3b597ff38  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
3b597fff8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
```

`hexdump` is also useful for having a look at difference at any other position in a file, in case a damage was caused deliberately by something.

Comment: thanks a lot, using *cmp* I've been able to compare the *.iso* and the DVD and, indeed, it ends "correctly" with an EOF. Now I understand better what's going on : )

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, both CDs and DVDs consist of a certain number of fixed-size blocks. The image that you're burning may not be a multiple of the block size, in which case the last block will contain some trailing garbage. So when you run `dd if=/dev/sr0` (which is an obfuscated way of writing `md5sum </dev/sr0`), the trailing garbage is included in the hash.

You need to keep track of the size of the image. Then apply the hash utility on the number of bytes of the payload (i.e. the ISO file).

```
</dev/sr0 head -c "$size" | md5sum
```

Comment: +1... oh gotcha and thanks *a lot*. So I may be taking into account trailing zero bytes or garbage. I'll see if I can use *cmp* instead.  *(now to be honest I don't know what's more obfuscated between using the pipe symbol and </dev/sr0 )*  ; )

Comment: CD sectors are 2,408 bytes long, but AFAIR DVD-ROMs write data in multiples of 16-sector blocks (so 32,768 bytes). `growisofs` produces an ISO image that's a multiple of 2,048 bytes, but maybe not a multiple of 32,768 bytes. That might explain why the CD checksums correctly and the DVD doesn't.